# adb Как При установке приложений на xiaomi каждый раз не спрашивать подтверждение

Tags: android, adb

Сейчас есть небольшой bash скрипт adb который автоматически устанавливает пулл приложений, 5 apk на смартфоны, с самсунгами все отлично, но xiaomi для каждого приложения спрашивает "установить приложение по usb или нет?" (больше того, еще стоит таймер, если за 30 секунд не подтвердить установку, приложение не установится) можно ли как то убрать это подтверждение? Чтобы приложения ставились сами на автомате.
Возможно я в настройках какого то важного разрешения не нашел? Включил вроде бы уже все что можно было

Answer (score 1):

Режим разработчика -> проверять приложение при установке